# Preferred way to handle creating a file if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I am writing a program that checks if a file exists. If it doesn't exist it creates it. After this, it reads the file. I am getting an "unhandled FileNotFoundException error" in Eclipse when I attempt to create a Scanner for it though. Here is the code snippet:

```
if(!NETWORK_FILE.exists()){
    try {
        NETWORK_FILE.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    //"ERROR" IS ON THE LINE BELOW
    Scanner read = new Scanner(NETWORK_FILE);

    while(read.hasNextLine()) {
        String fileSerial = read.nextLine();
        if(fileSerial.equals(serial)) {
            System.out.println("serial already exists");
            return;
        }
    }
    read.close();
}
```

I think it's pretty pointless to catch a FileNotFoundException because I specifically check and create the file right before this. Is there a "preferred way" of doing this?

Comment: That's life with checked exceptions. Just catch and ignore it.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of... thanks

Comment: Don't ignore it. Throw a runtime exception in case it is actually thrown. Either because a bug/regression is introduced, or because the file is indeed deleted between the time you check for its existence and the time you start reading from it. Ignoring exceptions is never a good idea. It just makes bugs harder to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question makes sense.
But checked exceptions work in this way.
The compiler doesn't make any association between distinct logical processings.
Note also that the application could be multi-threaded and the filesystem may be shared by multiple processes.
A file that exists at a time may not be any longer 1 second later.

In this specific case, I think that I would extract the handling of the exception in a specific method for example `createScannerWithExistingFile()` that would throw a `RuntimeException`. It would make the overall code logic 
clearer by isolating this `catch` statement :

```
if (!NETWORK_FILE.exists()) {
   ...
}

else {
    Scanner read = createScannerWithExistingFile(NETWORK_FILE);
    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
        String fileSerial = read.nextLine();
        if (fileSerial.equals(serial)) {
            System.out.println("serial already exists");
            return;
        }
    }
    read.close();

}

private Scanner createScannerWithExistingFile(File file) {
    try {
        return new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
        throw new RuntimeException("file " + f + " should exist", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed to your other way by using the path instead of the file. I'm already throwing an IOException in the method anyway so that way I think makes the most sense.

Comment: I updated it as after thinking I deemed that in your specific case  it didn't provide a great value as you could finish with two`catch (IOException)` at two distinct places according to the shown code. Finally, you throw the IOException ?

Comment: No need for a printStackTrace call if you’re chaining it to another exception.  That will just result in the same stack trace being printed twice: once in that catch block, then again as the “Caused by” portion of the RuntimeException’s stack trace.

Comment: @VGR Sure. I can't believe I wrote it. I hate duplicated stacktraces in logs ! I updated. Thanks :)